# Is there a better way for python post server to handle different file types?

Tags: python, post, error-handling, server

I have a post server written in python3.6.9, running on the localhost behind an apache2 reverse proxy. It receives a base64 file uploaded via Powershell and decodes them. Text Files get saved to the directory ./Public/example.txt.  If bytes are uploaded, it handles the error with 'except binascii.Error' and I can properly write it to the directory.  Both file types saved this way do so by taking the URI and replacing '/store.json' with nothing. If no FileName is present in post data, an 'except IOError' will write it to ./store.json in the current directory.

Here is the main code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Usage::
    ./server.py [<port>]
"""
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import logging
import base64
import json
import os
import datetime
import binascii
from os import curdir
from optparse import OptionParser
from os.path import join as pjoin
from pathlib import Path

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    store_path = pjoin(curdir, 'store.json')
    def _set_response(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        logging.info("GET request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n", str(self.path), str(self.headers))
        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("GET request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        try:
            b64_string = post_data
            post_data = base64.b64decode(b64_string)
            logging.info("POST request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n\nBody:\n%s\n",
                str(self.path), str(self.headers), post_data) #.decode('utf-8'))

        except binascii.Error as err:
            logging.info("POST request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n\nBody:\n%s\n",
                str(self.path), str(self.headers), post_data.decode('utf-8'))

        path = str(self.path)
        store_path = pjoin(curdir, 'store.json')
        for char in ' /':
            path = path.replace(char,'')
        path = path.replace("store.json", "")
        dirname='/opt/server/Public/'
        filename = path
        path = Path(dirname, filename)
        try:
            log_file = open(path, "wb")
            log_file.write(post_data)
            log_file.close()
            print("Wrote contents to %s." % path)
        except IOError:
            f=open(store_path, "ab+")
            f.write(post_data)
            f.close()
            log_file = open(store_path, "a")
            log_file.write("\n")
            log_file.write("%s\n" % datetime.datetime.now())
            log_file.write("\n")
            log_file.close()
            print("Wrote contents to %s." % store_path)

        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("POST request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))
```

I'm a beginner using python. I feel this is a sloppy way of handling files. Is there a better way to identify files without having my server 'error' its way into doing what I want? Also, do I always need to specify the error I am trying to handle?  In Powershell, I can lazily just try { catch { $_ } my way through automation.  I have looked for a while but haven't found a way to blindly handle errors in python. It always ends up hanging my server.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off welcome to SO.

So a few things that may help you out. People don't usually use python's `HTTPServer` unless you're wanting to control the lower part of http request and response. If you want to use a easy to use/setup http server `flask` is a great option as it will handle parsing POST data as well as saving files when they come through.

**Q1. Is there a better way to identity files?**

A1. This depends. During an http request to upload a file http standard is to upload the file name and extension along with the file's bytes. If you only upload bytes then most http servers will just ignore it and return an error. So if you send the name and extension along with the bytes than you know what kind of data it is and how to store it.

Also base64 is an encoding. So the only way to know if the encoding is good or not (malformed/dropped bytes) is to actually try and decode it and then catch any errors when it finds them. There is no way of asking it if it's a valid encoding without it actually trying to decode the data.

**Q2. Can you blindly handle errors in python?**

A2. Yes you can though it is discouraged to do so.

```
try:
   do_something()
except:
   print("I catch everything no matter what broke inside of this try")
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your quick response!  You have given me a lot to look into.  I really just wasn't sure if I was going in the right direction, though there is 1000 ways to do something.  I appreciate your insight.